# check difference using map() on arrays of object

Tags: javascript

So I thought of using `map()`,but I'm stuck. I want to return `arr2` but want to prompt the user whether there's changes or not by comparing it with `arr`. with below's approach, I got id of undefined if arr2 have any missing item.

https://jsfiddle.net/b13rbjyv/

```
var arr = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'something'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'something2'
}]

var arr2 = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'something'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'something2'
}]

var result = arr.map(function(obj, i) {
  if (obj.id == arr2[i].id) {
    return obj;
  }

})

document.write(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use filter

```
var result = arr.filter(function(obj, i) {
  return obj.id == arr2[i].id;
})
```

map should be used if you want to change object for instance if you need to have array of id only then you should use it. For example if you want to get list of ids then

```
var result = arr
.filter(function(obj, i) { return obj.id == arr2[i].id; })
.map(function(obj){return obj.id;});
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` returns an element for every given element of an array. It looks like what you need is actually to use `filter`. Perhaps something like this:

`var result = arr.filter((elem, index) => elem.id === arr2[index].id);`